# delete file from list forms folder

Tags: 2010, document-library

While following instructions [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/set-a-file-template-for-a-document-or-form-library-HA010377912.aspx) to add a custom template for a document library I uploaded the wrong file. (Basically I opened the list in Windows Explorer and navigated to the "Forms" subdirectory, where I pasted the file).

I am now unable to delete the file via Explorer - explorer will remove the file from view but if I "refresh" then it returns into view.

How do I delete the unnecessary file?

Answer (score 1):

> All site templates are saved in Content Database however you can un
> install then using the Uninstall-SPSolution powershell command

```
Uninstall-SPSolution [-Identity] <SPSolutionPipeBind> [-AssignmentCollection <SPAssignmentCollection>] [-Confirm [<SwitchParameter>]] [-Language <UInt32>] [-Local <SwitchParameter>] [-Time <String>] [-WhatIf [<SwitchParameter>]]
```

[MSDN tutorial for Uninstalling SPsolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607873.aspx)

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Thanks for responding. Unfortunately I don't see how that will help since I did not use a solution to install the templates.

Comment: you should give it a try tho it doesn't matter which way you installed it or uploaded it but you should try all ways you can un install it.

Comment: I don't have a solution! Just a file I copied into a folder via WebDav, per my question.